# Dart Future.delayed() without anonymous function with return value

Tags: dart

Is it possible to call `Future.delayed()` without using an anonymous function, and where the function returns a value? For example, here's `Future.delayed()` that doesn't use an anonymous function, but the function doesn't return a value:

```
void myFunc() {
  print("Hello from myFunc()");
}

void main() {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), myFunc);
}
```

How would I used `Future.delayed()` to call something like and get/use the return value:

```
int myFunc() {
  return 123;
}
```

?

Comment: You would use it... exactly like that. I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: By `awaiting` it and assigning the value to a variable like any other `Future` that returns a value, e.g. `final bar = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), myFunc);`

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the answer! Had no idea it worked like this. It did mean, however, that I had to change the signature of `myFunc()` to `Future<int> myFunc() async {...}`. I'll gladly accept your comment as the answer if you post it as an answer.

Comment: Actually, I don't have to change the signature of `int myFunc()` if I do: `final bar = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => myFunc());`. Again - thanks so much for this, it has cleared up a bunch of things for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Future.delayed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html) takes a *computation* that will run after the delay. The result of this computation will be returned. So you can do this:

```
int myFunc() {
  return 123;
}

void main() async {
  final result = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), myFunc);
  
  print(result);
}
```